# Generic number class code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just made a generic number class:

- From any ordered character list, make number class representing that ordered character list.
- `create_number_class("01")` returns binary number class
- `create_number_class("0123456789")` returns decimal number class
- `create_number_class("abcdefghij")` return decimal number class but representing each digit as a alphabet.

Here is the generic number class definition. I think it is well-made class definition. Is there something needed for improvement in that class definition?

Example:

```
ABC_Class = create_number_class("abc")
x = ABC_Class("baa")
y = ABC_Class("bbb")
print(x+y)
#output digits: abc, v: cbb, decimal_v: 22
```

Here is the class definition:

```
def create_number_class(alphabet):
    class temp(object):
        digits = alphabet
        def __init__(self, v):
            self.v = v
            self.decimal_v = self.to_decimal(self)
        @staticmethod
        def to_decimal(self):
            r = 0
            for i in range(0, len(self.v)):
                r += len(temp.digits)**(len(self.v)-i-1)*(temp.digits.index(self.v[i]))
            return r
        @classmethod
        def from_decimal(cls, decimal_v):
            r = []
            mod = len(temp.digits)
            if decimal_v < mod:
                return cls(temp.digits[decimal_v])
            while True:
                remainder = decimal_v % mod
                r.append(remainder)
                decimal_v = int((decimal_v - remainder)/ mod)
                if decimal_v < mod:
                    r.append(decimal_v)
                    break
            r = "".join(list(reversed([temp.digits[x] for x in r])))
            #r = "".join(list(reversed([str(temp.digits.index(str(x))) for x in r])))
            return cls(r)
        def __add__(self, other):
            return temp.from_decimal(self.decimal_v+other.decimal_v)
        def __sub__(self, other):
            return temp.from_decimal(self.decimal_v-other.decimal_v)
        def __mul__(self, other):
            return temp.from_decimal(self.decimal_v*other.decimal_v)
        def __floordiv__(self, other):
            return temp.from_decimal(self.decimal_v//other.decimal_v)
        def __str__(self):
            return "digits: {}, v: {}, decimal_v: {}".format(temp.digits, self.v, self.decimal_v)
        def convert_to(self, new_class):
            return new_class.from_decimal(self.decimal_v)
    return temp
```

Here is an example:

```
BinClass = create_number_class("01")
DecimalClass = create_number_class("0123456789")

x = BinClass("111")
x = BinClass("1000")
y = BinClass("10")

HexClass = create_number_class('0123456789ABCDEF')
x = HexClass('1')
y = HexClass('AA')

print(x+y)
print(x-y)
print(x*y)
print(x//y)
print(x.convert_to(DecimalClass))
isinstance(x, BinClass)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks very good for me, what I found are just some minor improvements:

1. You do not need to inherit from object so you can just do `class temp:`
2. I would suggest to change temporary class name to something else since when you do `print(type(x))` I would rather see something more informative than `<class '__main__.create_number_class.<locals>.temp'>`. I would suggest to add another argument for your method called `className` and set it dynamically as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352781/how-to-set-class-names-dynamically)
3. New lines after each method would be appreciated since it would make code more readable